# OpenCV3.3 CUDA stack smashing

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed OpenCV3.3 with CUDA in ubuntu 16.04.
I tried to build OpenCV with CUDA sample code.
Code compile succeeded but I faced following error message when I executed binary.

error message is "*** stack smashing detected ***: ./test terminated
Aborted (core dumped)"

I want to delete this error message. How do I fix code or settings ?

my test code is

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // view OpenCV build information
    std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;

    // view CUDA infomation
    int dev_id = cv::cuda::getDevice();
    std::cout << "cuda get device id is " << dev_id << " getCudaEnabledDeviceCount is " << cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() << std::endl;
    cv::cuda::setDevice(dev_id);
    cv::cuda::printCudaDeviceInfo(dev_id);
    cv::cuda::resetDevice();
}
```

and message

```
----------

General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-08-23T01:49:09Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.5.1
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2
      SSE4_1 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (7 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef dow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -mssisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef dow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -mssisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissin-Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse-DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissin-Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse-O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-li-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so gstbase-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 gstvideo-1.0 gstapp-1.0 gstriff-1.0 gstpbutils-1.0 dc1394 avcodec-ffmpeg avformat-ffmpeg avutle-ffmpeg dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so cudart nppc nppi npps cublas cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml objdetect video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping dnn imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui features2d calib3bjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab python3
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts viz

  GUI:
    QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.5.1)
    QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.5.1)
    OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.4)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      avresample:                YES (ver 2.1.0)
    GStreamer:
      base:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.8.3)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.8.3)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.8.3)
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    Aravis SDK:                  NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
    Intel Media SDK:             NO
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9002)

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use Intel IPP:               2017.0.2 [2017.0.2]
               at:               /home/test/OpenCv/opencv-3.3.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
    Use Intel IPP IW:            prebuilt binaries (2017.0.2)
    Use Intel IPP Async:         NO
    Use VA:                      NO
    Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.92)
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  YES
    USE NVCUVID:                 YES
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
    NVIDIA PTX archs:
    Use fast math:               YES

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                /home/test/OpenCv/opencv-3.3.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
    numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
    packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           NO
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  /usr/local

  cvconfig.h is in:              /home/test/OpenCv/opencv-3.3.0/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------


cuda get device id is 0 getCudaEnabledDeviceCount is 1
*** CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking) ***

Device count: 1

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1080"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 8112 MBytes (8506048512 bytes)
  GPU Clock Speed:                               1.73 GHz
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(131072), 2D=(131072,65536), 3D=(16384,16384,16384)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(32768) x 2048, 2D=(32768,32768) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           2 / 0
  Compute Mode:
      Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously)

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version  = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1

*** stack smashing detected ***: ./test terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
----------
```

How fixed this error?

Answer (score 0):

I get "stack smashing" quite often.  The CUDA code is in a static library, linked in a simple CLI executable.  A Clean Rebuild always makes it go away.  I suspect my IDE is not rebuilding and relinking edited files as it should.